# How do I pass events between Backbone.js views?

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events

I'm excercizing with my first Backbone app, CRUD style.
I have `modelListView`, with an Edit button linking to the `modelView`. The modelView has a delete button to destroy the model.

Now what I want to achieve is to show user a success message when he returns to the `modelListView` and when the model has been successfully deleted.

I have triggered a `model:deleted` event within `success` but the `modelListView`'s listener:

```
        initialize: function(){
            this.on('wine:deleted', function(){
                alert('wine:deleted')
            })
        },
```

can't "hear" that. What is the best practice for that sort of inter-view communication?

Comment: did you check this out? http://addyosmani.github.io/backbone-fundamentals/#on-off-and-trigger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of approaches I've used. One is to have both views hold references to the same model - then you can simply listen for events from the model in question from whichever view needs to know about it. The second is to use an [event aggregator](http://addyosmani.github.io/backbone-fundamentals/#event-aggregators-and-mediators), essentially an event object that provides a place to route events through so you can reduce the number of objects you need to have your views listening to events from. Which I use is generally guided by the complexity of the application and how many model/collection objects from which I need to route events.

Comment: The idea of an event bus attracts me more. I thought there's a built in way or a trick to achieve my goal. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think your basic problem is this line:

```
this.on('wine:deleted', function(){
```

you said that line of code came from `modelListView`, but the thing is, `Views` don't have an `on` method (only `Model`s and `Collection`s do).  I think what you're looking for is:

```
this.model.on('wine:deleted', function(){
```

but even that's not quite right because the namespacing seems funny.  If I assume you're doing:

```
this.trigger('deleted');
```

in your Wine model, then to catch that event you'd just need:

```
this.model.on('deleted', function(){
```

However, even that seems like a bit of overkill, because Backbone already has an event that you can use when a `Model` gets destroyed, that doesn't require any extra `trigger` statements:

```
this.model.on('destroy' function(){
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I would have cluttered my space with unnecessary events.